# RecyclerView not fetching data from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app where i have to fetch some data from firebase and show in recyclerview. But the textView fields remain empty and show no data. Below is the db structure. I want to get the data of the nodes under "AlphabetMatching" but failing to get it. The Recycler show the layout i have made for the rows, but no data from the database.

[image]

---

Activity Class:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alphabet_matching_perf);



    mlinearLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    //mlinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
   // mlinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);


    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.am_recycler);



    db_ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Performance");
    user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    userID=user.getUid();

    alphabetMatchingPerfRef= db_ref.child(userID).child("AlphabetMatching");


    //Toast.makeText(this, alphabetMatchingPerfRef.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    showData();




}

public void showData()
{

    options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<amaw>().setQuery(alphabetMatchingPerfRef,amaw.class).build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<amaw, ViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull amaw model) {
            holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),model.getDate(),model.getTime(),model.getScore());


        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View itemView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.performancelayout,parent,false);

            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
            return holder;
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mlinearLayoutManager);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

---

VIEWHOLDER CLASS:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

View mView;



public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);


    mView=itemView;

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });


}

public void setDetails(Context ctx,String date, String time, String score)
{
    TextView mdate=mView.findViewById(R.id.date_box);
    TextView mtime=mView.findViewById(R.id.time_box);
    TextView mscore=mView.findViewById(R.id.score_box);
}
```

}

---

AMAW CLASS

```
public class amaw {

String date;
String score;
String time;

String username;

public amaw(String datee, String time, String score) {
    this.date = datee;
    this.time = time;
    this.score = score;
}

public amaw() {

}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String datee) {
    this.date = datee;
}


public String getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
public void setDetails(Context ctx,String date, String time, String score)
{
    TextView mdate=mView.findViewById(R.id.date_box);
    TextView mtime=mView.findViewById(R.id.time_box);
    TextView mscore=mView.findViewById(R.id.score_box);
}
```

Into this:

```
public void setDetails(Context ctx,String date, String time, String score)
{
    TextView mdate=mView.findViewById(R.id.date_box);
    TextView mtime=mView.findViewById(R.id.time_box);
    TextView mscore=mView.findViewById(R.id.score_box);
    mdate.setText(date);
    mtime.setText(time);
    mscore.setText(score);
}
```